# Hide from other users the folders they do not have read and execute permissions

Tags: permissions

For the sake of this question, assume there is User1 and User2, besides the root user of course.

I want to share (rx) with User2 an specific folder within User1 home (say, `/home/User1/Music/Aerosmith/`). I can use `chmod` for the respective permissions and all is fine: User2 can explore and play the content of that folder. Now, as User2 moves into the shared folder, she can actually see **all** the other subfolders present at each stage (e.g. it can see that there is a folder called `/home/User1/Music/Madonna`) even though she cannot access them. Now, what I want is for User2 to **only** see the folders she is allowed to read and execute, hiding all the other things I'm not sharing with her. Folders need to be invisible either from a GUI perspective (say, in Thunar) or using `ls`.

I can't find a solution for this. Is it just impossible from the command line perspective?

Comment: So you want to give permissions of only /home/User1/Music and its subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the read permission for others (or group, if `user2` is part of `user1`'s primary group) from the directories in the tree:

```
chmod o-r /home/User1 -R
chmod o+r /home/User1/Music/Aerosmith/Rocks -R
```

As long as the execute permissions remain, User2 will be able to traverse the directory tree, but not see the contents.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Now User2 can move along the folders it has execute permission but it cannot see **any** folder, not even those that it has execute rights. Thus, in order to change folder User2 has to know in advance the names of the folders. THis applies both to GUI (thunar) and terminal. (`ls` show permission denied). What I want is for User2 to see **only** the folders it has execution permissions, not all (with rx) nor any (with x).